# UIDocumentPickerViewController - How to import/export files from iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I googed it and then i comes to know the process how to get file from `iCloud` account

```
- (void)showDocumentPickerInMode:(UIDocumentPickerMode)mode {
UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", @"com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers", @"com.apple.iwork.keynote.key"] inMode:mode];

documentPicker.delegate = self;
documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
if (controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerModeImport) {
    NSString *alertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Successfully imported %@", [url lastPathComponent]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                              alertControllerWithTitle:@"Import"
                                              message:alertMessage
                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}
}
```

But in run time i am getting an warning like:

> Warning: Attempt to present `<UIDocumentPickerViewController:> 0x14ed4f2b0>`

on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I am unable to open `UIDocumentPickerViewController`

**Can you please help me out (How to enable `iCloud` entitlements for Development certificate in Apple account) & how i can i solve this issue**
[image]

Comment: Look at this code: `[self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil]`. Wether the `ViewController` which represents `self` displays modally? If you have attempted to push that?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with iCloud. It's how you are presenting the document picker. What is `self` in the code you posted? Is it currently on screen at the time you call `presentViewController:animated:completion:`?

Comment: That's what @ rmaddy, Basically i am new to this concept, I tought Once presentViewController: is called, your user is presented(i am little bit struck here..) an Apple-provided UI for selecting a file from the document provider. At this time the user has access to all of the enabled third-party providers installed on their device.